# Can I sample from a distribution whose parameters depend on the current iteration?

Tags: random, distributions, homework, procedural-programming

Let's say I want to sample from 100 Beta distributions, and in each successive one, the first parameter increases by 1. So given a current iteration number `n`, I want to make a list of

```
RandomVariate[ BetaDistribution[n, b] ]
```

for all `n` values from 1 to 100. Is there an easy way to do this in Mathematica? I assume I would be able to find a way without needing to define 100 different distributions.

Edit 2: I changed the distribution I was talking about slightly--I'm asking this as a general question, the actual distribution I'm trying to sample from is a little more complicated but I'm hoping that if there's a solution that works for this, I can apply that solution elsewhere.

Edit: I thought this was possible with a For loop but after trying it out looks like I was wrong. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, sv], 100] + Range@100`...

Comment: @ciao Sorry, I'll edit my OP, I forgot that Normal distributions can just be shifted like that. What I'm asking is if there's a more general way to do this--I want to be able to apply this to, say, the standard deviation instead of the mean, or to another distribution altogether. My example was just a simple example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. The example that I gave can be done (if we want to do it in one line) with:

```
RandomVariate[#]&/@(BetaDistribution[#,b]&/@Range[100]);
```

If we wanted to do the same thing for both variables, we could do something instead like

```
RandomVariate[#]&/@(MapThread[BetaDistribution[#1,#2]&,{Range[100],Range[100]}]);
```

This seems pretty slow right now for what I'm using it for, so if anyone has any optimization suggestions let me know!

Comment: `RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[#, b], 1][[1]] & /@ Range[100]` is about 6 times faster (although neither approach seems slow).

Comment: @JimB Thanks! It looks like the slowness was because I was using `CategoricalDistribution` in my code where `BernoulliDistribution` was just as useful and also faster.